# Use ArcGIS basemap vector tile in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, vector-tiles, vector-layer

I want to use this on my school project, I searched many ways but still not.

https://basemaps.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/OpenStreetMap_v2/VectorTileServer From https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=80be160f0ca1413d898ad4e90d197278

I tried adjusting the code as I learned but it doesn't work.

This it what I tried

```js
var OpenStreetMap_v2 = L.tileLayer(
    'https://basemaps.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/OpenStreetMap_v2/VectorTileServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.pbf',
    { maxZoom: 18
});
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not the most descriptive way to state a problem.

Comment: @Vince It doesn't show me results.  But it’s work when I done with ``` varEsriworldImagery = L.tileLayer ('http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
{ maxZoom: 18
});                                              ```

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: Tiles you are trying to use are vector tiles, so you can't display them with standard Leaflet `L.tileLayer` raster tiles layer. You have to use `Leaflet.VectorGrid` plugin, see https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid.